# is there any way to define javascript schema

Tags: javascript

I have question , As we have XSD for defining the legal building blocks of an XML document do we have any similar schema language to define javascript elements.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What *exactly* would a JavaScript schema define? Are you talking about JSON?

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript schema builder [tool](http://javascript-schema-builder.fyxm.net/) also:

Answer (score 0):

If by "javascript" you mean the document object model (DOM), then I suppose the various interfaces could be expressed as an XML schema, however there are a large number of separate specifications and standards covering the DOM ([Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/), [Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/), [Style](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/), [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/) and so on) so I doubt that any one XSD could cover more than say 20% of it.

Also, there is an awful lot of information in the various specifications that can't fit into an XSD, such as page load processing, form behaviour, image and XML file procssing and so on.

How would you include the entirety of HTML5 as a single schema?